# converting dates in SAS and creating a new variable

Tags: sas, formatting

Lets say I have the following dates for the observations

```
data dates;
input obs date$11.;
cards;
    1   06/10/1949
    2   01/07/1952
    3   02/10/1947
;
run;
```

But now I want to insert another column next to date called new date under the `date9.` format and this new date column is to be numeric.

I tried the following,

```
data newdata;
set dates;
newdate=input(date,date9.);
run;
```

But when I run this, the new date column seems to be empty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your string values are not using a format that is compatible with the `DATE.` informat. They appear to be using either `MMDDYY.` or `DDMMYY.`, but it is not possible to tell which from your example values.

```
data dates;
  input obs datestr :$11.;
  date1 = input(datestr,mmddyy10.);
  date2 = input(datestr,ddmmyy10.);
  format date1 date2 date9. ;
cards;
1   06/10/1949
2   01/07/1952
3   02/10/1947
;
```

results:

```
Obs    obs     datestr          date1        date2

 1      1     06/10/1949    10JUN1949    06OCT1949
 2      2     01/07/1952    07JAN1952    01JUL1952
 3      3     02/10/1947    10FEB1947    02OCT1947
```